# swagger securityDefinition with Resteasy

Tags: token, swagger, resteasy, swagger-ui, api-key

I did configure swagger with an Application subclass and the beanConfig object, my securityDefinition must allow swagger ui to show de api_key field to allow authentication for all my services layer.

```
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
    beanConfig.setHost("192.168.4.9:8080");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/cjppa/rest");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.cjppa.fpuna.backend.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);

    io.swagger.models.Info info = new io.swagger.models.Info();
    io.swagger.models.Contact contact = new io.swagger.models.Contact();
    info.setVersion("1.0");
    beanConfig.setInfo(info);

    io.swagger.models.auth.ApiKeyAuthDefinition apikey = new 
    io.swagger.models.auth.ApiKeyAuthDefinition();
    apikey.setName("x-token");
    apikey.setIn(In.HEADER);


    Swagger swagger = new Swagger().info(info);
    swagger.securityDefinition("api_key", apikey);

    beanConfig.configure(swagger);
```

the expected api_key comes in the "x-token" http header

Comment: extracted from pet store example bootstraped servlet , i added new SwaggerContextService().updateSwagger(swagger); at the end

Answer (score 2):

I tried also to bring swagger into my resteasy webservice with using BasicAuthentification for some operations of my webservice. I imported swagger via maven in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.18</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Application class I configured the BeanConfig:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;



@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application{

public Application() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("de.mycompany.topic.ws");

    beanConfig.setBasePath("/de.mycompany.topic.ws/rest/");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
}
```

The important thing is to configure the BasicAuthentification in an ReaderListener implementation via Annotations. `basicAuth` is an arbitrary name.

```
import io.swagger.annotations.BasicAuthDefinition;
import io.swagger.annotations.SecurityDefinition;
import io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.ReaderListener;
import io.swagger.models.Swagger;

@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(basicAuthDefinitions = {
    @BasicAuthDefinition(key = "basicAuth")
    }) )
public class SwaggerCustomizeDefinition implements ReaderListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {
    }
}
```

In MyRestService I annotate my operations that should be not usable without basic authentification. See here e.g. for saving customers:

```
@Api
@Path("/")
public class MyRestService {
private final static String UTF8 = ";charset=UTF-8";

@POST
    @Path("/customer")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + UTF8)
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "Saves customer specified in the body",
        notes = "note that appears in swagger ui",
        authorizations = {
            @Authorization(value = "basicAuth", scopes={})
        })
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "customer created"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "customer format not supported"),
    })
    public Response saveCustomer(
        String content,
        @BasicAuthDefinition(key = "basicAuth") @HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization) {

        // authorization
        try {
            if (!MyManager.isAuthorized(authorization)) {
                return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }

        //do the work, authorization was ok
    }
}
```

That's it. I tried a lot of variations and this was the only one that works for me in whole. My main problem was, that the authorize button not appears in the ui and the lock above the single methods in the swagger ui was not clickable so that the basic authentification modal dialog not appears. With this implementation it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can implements io.swagger.jaxrs.config.ReaderListener ,addSecurity in afterScan method . eg:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(apiKeyAuthDefinitions = {
    @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, key = "token", name = "E-token"),
    @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, key = "userId", name = "E-userId"),
    @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, key = "corpId", name = "E-corpId") }) )
public class SwaggerCustomizeDefinition implements ReaderListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {
        swagger.addSecurity(new SecurityRequirement().requirement("token"));
        swagger.addSecurity(new SecurityRequirement().requirement("userId"));
        swagger.addSecurity(new SecurityRequirement().requirement("corpId"));
    }

}
```